# Django: lookup for many to many relation

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-queryset

I have following models:

```
class Name(models.Model):
    name = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
    primary = models.BooleanField()
    project = models.ForeignKey(
        Project, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="names")

class Robject(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(to=Project, null=True, blank=True)
    names = models.ManyToManyField(
        "Name",
        related_name="robjects",
        limit_choices_to= limit_name_choices,
        blank=True
    )

    [...]
```

I'm looking for Name filter lookup, which gives me only names that have no relations to any robject.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a simple filter:

```
Name.objects.filter(robjects=None)
```